# Way to bypass CSP limitations

Tags: lightning, integration, google-drive, csp

We store images of our customers in Google Drive. Way we merge data is by Rest API calls. Also, we provide our managers with custom lightning component with embeded links to the images. Unfortunately, after winter'19 the componed stoped to work. I don't really know the whole underlying problem, but now it says the following

> Refused to load the image
>   'https://doc-0c-64-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/{IMAGE METADATA}'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "img-src 'self' data: blob

Yeah, I know that it's due to CSP, but the domain isn't constant, i.e. `doc-0c-64-docs` could change to `doc-0o-1c-docs` or something like that, and  I simply can't add every single domain to CSP.

As I can't use wildcards  (*), what are my options here?

Much thanks in advance!